# Running JavaFX 8 applications in Java 10 rendered in bigger windows and differently styled contents

Tags: java, windows, javafx, javafx-8, java-10

For a while I've been developing JavaFX applications in Java 8 and I recently upgraded to Java 10 which still includes JavaFX. Attempting to run my previously created applications leads to uglier-looking applications. The window is much larger than what it should be and everything is bigger than normal. To demonstrate with one of my [GitHub applications](https://github.com/mattwright324/youtube-comment-suite):

[image]

I am able to reproduce this by uninstalling (and installing Java 8) running the application and then reinstalling Java 10 and running the application. Were there changes to JavaFX in 10 that could cause this? Is there anyway to fix it or do I just recommend users to stay on Java 8?

Comment: Are you using default sizes? In terms of size, it just looks like the containers may have grown, whereas the text looks the same size. Maybe the default sizes for some of the containers you used have been changed.

Comment: To clarify, you are running JavaFX code compiled in Java 8 and running the code on Java 10? If so, what happens if you compile the code with Java 10?

Comment: @HypnicJerk Many of the nodes using default sizes looks to be fine now that I look at it. Most of the nodes that modify font size and node width/height look to be the ones that are bigger than normal.

Comment: @Slaw Yes I am running 8-compiled code and running it in 10. I have not tried recompiling in Java 10 but will see if that changes anything.

Comment: @Slaw Using IntelliJ, I changed the project SDK between Java 8 JDK and Java 10 JDK and ran the application so that it would compile and run with the different Java versions. Nothing has changed, Java 10 still makes the application larger than normal.

Comment: After some research and looking deeper into the problem something relating to [dpi scaling changes in Java 9](http://news.kynosarges.org/2018/01/26/javafx-dpi-scaling-in-java-9/) appear to be related. Adding `-Dglass.win.uiScale=100%` to the VM arguments sets the windows back to expected size though it isn't perfectly the same as it used to be. Does this mean the larger-scaled application is the correct appearance for my 125% scaled Windows display setting for the screen?